# What is the meaning of the expression, "I'll cut you in" for something!

Tags: slang

here the examples to show you what I need to know ... and Is it a phrasal verb? and is this word used informally as slang?

> 1. The proposed across-the-board cuts for all state agencies will total $84 million.
> 2. I cut you for a 100$

Comment: It's not slang in either of those usages. Think of an across-the-board budget cut as visually similar to a haircut. The excess hair is trimmed to reflect a new style. So too the budget is 'cut' because the company wants to limit their spending. To cut someone for $100 is slightly ambiguous. It could refer to the act of cutting their body, causing them to bleed, in order to gain $100; or cutting in front of them in line, in exchange for $100. The latter is a fair trade, while the former is a threat to extort money.

Comment: Could mean "I'll cut you *in* for $100," so your part of the venture is $100.

Comment: It seems Thatso should provide the context for question 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the 2nd one is supposed to be "I will cut you in for $100." If that is what you meant to say, then it means that you will allow the person to participate for $100. For example, if you were making a bet on a race horse for $1000, and I wanted to participate in that bet, then you could cut me in for $100, so that I would pay you $100 and if our horse wins, then I get 10% of the winnings and you get 90% of the winnings. In essence, you have allowed me to cut into your stake by 10%.

The other example of the use of "cut" is straight forward, it means literally a "cut" of financing equal to $84 million. In other words, the state agency will receive 84 million fewer dollars after the cuts.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yeah, I looked it up (cut) on the dictionaries, it holds  lots of meaning, but the one that I want is share.... thanks guys